# Formatting with setw() c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an organized looking graph with the amount of money for each food under each month. I was able to line up the first row, but after that, something started going off. This is what I ended up with:[image: Current Output]

This is the code I tried playing around with the setw() but I can't seem to change it for the number after it puts out the first array element.

```
void sales_report() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << setw(17) << months[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << foods[0] << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        sumapple += apples[i];
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(8) << money << apples[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(8) << money << sumapple << endl;
    cout << foods[1] << " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        sumoranges += oranges[i];
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(7) << money << oranges[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(7) << money << sumoranges << endl;
    cout << foods[2] << " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        sumpears += pears[i];
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(10) << money << pears[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(10) << money << sumpears << endl;
    cout << foods[3] << " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        sumtomatoes += tomatoes[i];
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(7) << money << tomatoes[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(7) << money << sumtomatoes << endl;
    cout << foods[4] << " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        sumcherries += cherries[i];
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(6) << money << cherries[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(6) << money << sumcherries << endl << totalmonth;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        total = apples[i] + oranges[i] + pears[i] + tomatoes[i] + cherries[i];
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(9) << money << total << " ";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using different [std::setw()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) values in each of the `for` loops. Hence the misalignment. Use the same values.

Comment: That worked for the spacing problem, but if I keep them all the same how do I makeup for the fact that the food names are different lengths

Comment: Use the `std::setw(15)` for example when printing out those too. You don't set the width currently.

Comment: My teacher won't allow it. He said we are only allowed to align right and if I apply setw to those then it will move the word to the right. I know it would be easy to just use left and it would look fine in output but its not allowed for this.

Comment: @t.slez Are you allowed to calculate the length of the string with the food name (please, tell me it's a `std::string`...) and then adjust the width of the first price accordingly?

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the width of the first price within the for loop?